# Can’t get random generated string to print itself

Tags: python

I am currently working on a custom made version of a random password generator. When I run my program, it creates the desired 11 character password, but then it prints a different password with various random characters right below it. How can I avoid this?

The desired outcome would be for it to generate a random 11 character password and then confirm it back to the user by printing it.

```
import string
import random

def generate():
    generated_pwd = string.ascii_letters
    print("Generating...")
    print(" ")
    print("Your randomly generated key is ")
    print(''.join(random.choice(generated_pwd) for i in range(11)))
    return generated_pwd

def add():
    username = input("What is usernme:")
    pwd = input("What is password: (for random, type 'generate') ")
    if pwd == 'generate' :
        generated_pwd = generate()
        print(generated_pwd)
        pwd = generated_pwd
        print("your password is " + pwd)
        return generated_pwd
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow - I see it has been a very long time. Please read [ask] and the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), and make sure you understand how to post code so that it shows up properly with the correct indentation, exactly as you actually have it. Try to **ask a question**, clearly, starting with a question word like "why" or "how" and ending with a question mark (`?`). Explain **what the problem is**: *what happens* when you run the code? What is *supposed to happen instead*, and *how is that different*?

Comment: Please fix your indentation. If you call `add()`, and add appropriate imports for `string` and `random`, it would appear your code already does what you need - what is the problem? Did you miss the fact that you generate a password in `generate()`, but don't assign the result to `generated_pwd` (you just print it)?

Comment: If there is an error message, [show a complete error message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146), copied and pasted, starting with the line that says `Traceback (most recent call last):` until the end, and formatted like code. But first please try to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the code yourself, so that you at least can explain where you are stuck or what you don't understand about the error.

Comment: Finally: for the future, it will help you a lot to learn proper terminology. Variables are not "called"; functions are. The way to get information back from a function is with `return`; think carefully about what should be `return`ed, and make sure you understand that `print` has **nothing to do with** `return`.

Answer (score 1):

`generate()` returns `generated_pwd` which is just `str.ascii_letters`. In `generate()` you print the random password but just return `str.ascii_letters` so that is what gets printed in `add()`.

You want to put your random password in a variable, print the variable, and return the same variable. Change `generate()` like this:

```
def generate():
    print("Generating...\n")
    generated_pwd = "".join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for i in range(11))
    print(f"Your randomly generated key is {generated_pwd}")
    return generated_pwd
```

Comment: Wow this totally did it. Thank you! Now I understand what I did wrong. 
I appreciate  it.